# MCMC in Gibbs: Threshold Multivariate Linear Regression

Tags: self-study, bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, threshold

I have a problem regarding what I expected to be a rather straightforward modelling approach: I want to investigate multivariate linear regression parameters and a thresholding parameter which defines 2 different regimes for the data. For simulated data my sampler converges extremely fast to the true threshold value and Bayesian inference suggests virtually no estimation uncertainty which makes me wonder if I did something wrong. **Why is identification of a threshold so seemingly easy?**

---

Edit: My initial question turned out to be way to naive, instead, I ask: **when is identification easy and what can I do to identify this cases?**

---

Suppose you have data of the form $Y\in\mathbb{R}^{T \times N}$, $X\in\mathbb{R}^{T \times K}$ and $r\geq0$. The data can be separated by a threshold $r$ such that 
$$Y^0 :=\{Y: |X_{i,L}|<r\} \text{ and } X^0 :=\{X: |X_{i,L}|<r\}$$ for some (known) column $L$ of $X$. Similar, $$Y^1 :=\{Y: |X_{i,L}|\geq r\} \text{ and } X^1 :=\{X: |X_{i,L}|\geq r\}.$$ The respective size of the partitioned matrices is $Y^0 \in\mathbb{R}^{T^0 \times N}$ and $Y^1 \in\mathbb{R}^{T^1 \times N}$ with $T^0 + T^1 =T$. 
The underlying data-generating process takes the form:

$$Y^i = X^i\beta^i+U^i \text{ for } i\in\{0,1\} \text{ where }U^i \sim MN(0, \Sigma^i).$$
$r$ is not known ex-ante, so the set of parameters to estimate is $\theta:=\{\beta^0, \beta^i, \Sigma^0, \Sigma^1, r\}$. 
Obviously, conditional on $r$, standard inference from Bayesian multivariate linear regression models applies, but for the sake of completeness I provide the corresponding setup:

- The likelihood takes the form 
  $$L(Y|\theta,X) \propto \prod\limits_{i\in\{0, 1\}}|\Sigma^i|^{-T^i/2}\exp{\left(-1/2\text{tr}\left({\Sigma^i}^{-1}{U^i}'U^i\right)\right)}$$
- Priors are chosen to be conditional conjugate for $\beta^i, \Sigma^i$:
  $$p(\Sigma^i)\sim IW(V, v) \text{ and } p(\beta^i|\Sigma^i)\sim MN(B, \Sigma^i)$$
- The prior for $r$ is strictly positive, assume for now it is uniform such that
  $p(r) \sim U[0,b)$ with some $b>0$.

**Posterior inference:** 
A standard Gibbs sampling scheme applies for the posterior when conditioning on $r$ (See [here (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_multivariate_linear_regression]) for the conditional posterior distributions).

Basically, given an initial (or sampled) value of $r$ I do the following: 
- Separate the data $Y$ and $X$ (some consistency check necessary to ensure $T^0$ and $T^1$ are large enough). 
- Inverse Wishart draw to draw from $\Sigma^0$ and $\Sigma^1$
- Multivariate normal draw to sample from $\beta^0|\Sigma^0$ and $\beta^1|\Sigma^1$.

Now, the part where I want to make use of a random walk metropolis hastings (RWMH) step within Gibbs: **sampling from $p(r|\beta^0, \beta^1, \Sigma^0, \Sigma^1, Y, X)$**: RWMH requires evaluation of the (non-normalized) conditional posterior distribution which can be evaluated as follows:
$p(r| \beta^0, \beta^1, \Sigma^0, \Sigma^1, Y, X) \propto L(Y|\theta,X).$ (The prior for $r$ does not show up due to the uniform assumption. Therefore, given a proposal draw $\log (r^\text{new})$ sampled from $N(\log(r^\text{old}),c^2)$ where $r^\text{old}$ is the recent (initial) value, I evaluate the likelihood ratio of $r^\text{old}$ and $r^\text{new}$:

- **Acceptance ratio** $$\alpha(r^\text{new}|r^\text{old}) = \min\left(1, \frac{L(Y|r^\text{new}, \beta^0, \beta^1, \Sigma^0, \Sigma^1, X)r^\text{new}}{L(Y|r^\text{old}, \beta^0, \beta^1, \Sigma^0, \Sigma^1, X)r^\text{old}}\right)$$
- Likelihood $L(Y|r^\text{new}, \beta^0, \beta^1, \Sigma^0, \Sigma^1, X)$ depends on $r^\text{new}$ due to different segmentation of $Y$ and $X$ as shown above. Values of $\beta^0, \beta^1, \Sigma^1, \Sigma^0$ are kept constant, though, for both evaluated likelihoods due to the conditioning. Therefore, letting $\tilde T^i$ the sample size of $Y^i$ based on the new segmentation due to $r^\text{new}$ and $\tilde U^i$ the corresponding residuals $\tilde Y^i - \tilde X^i\beta^i$ , I get:
  $$\log\left(\frac{L(Y|r^\text{new}, \beta^0, \beta^1, \Sigma^0, \Sigma^1, X)r^\text{new}}{L(Y|r^\text{old}, \beta^0, \beta^1, \Sigma^0, \Sigma^1, X)r^\text{old}}\right) = \frac{(T^0 - \tilde T ^0)}{2} |\Sigma^0| + \frac{(T^1 - \tilde T ^1)}{2} |\Sigma^1| + \frac{1}{2}\text{tr}({\Sigma^0}^{-1}({U^0}'U^0-{\tilde U^0}'\tilde U^0) + {\Sigma^1}^{-1}({U^1}'U^1-{\tilde U^1}'\tilde U^1 )) + log(\frac{r^\text{new}}{r^\text{old}})$$

**Estimation and simulation**
I simulate data based on the description above and let my sampler run to draw inference regarding all unknown parameters exactly the way described above. I sample 2000 draws (+ 2000 burn in) and discard every 2nd draw ot reduce autocorrelation. My tuning parameter $c$ for the proposal distribution is set such that the acceptance ratio is roughly 15%.
The resulting draws for $r$ look as follows (true value is $r=0.4$):
[image: Posterior draws for r (true value is 0.4)]

**However, setting `r_true=0.32` suddenly prevents the sampler from correctly identifying the threshold. Why?**

```
# Simulate data

set.seed(3010)
T <- 5000
N <- 4
K <- 3

# (X[,K+1] determines which regime we are in)

X <- matrix(rnorm(T*(K-1)), nrow=T)
X <- cbind(1, X)

b_true_0 <- rnorm(N*K)
B_true_0 <- matrix(b_true_0, nr=K)

b_true_1 <- rnorm(N*K)
B_true_1 <- matrix(b_true_1, nr=K)

# Sigma is set to Identity matrix in both states

r_true <- 0.4
regime_true <- abs(X[,K])<r_true

Y <- matrix(rnorm(T*N), nrow=T)
Y[regime_true==TRUE,] <- Y[regime_true==TRUE,] +         
X[regime_true==TRUE,]%*%B_true_0  
Y[regime_true==FALSE,] <- Y[regime_true==FALSE,] +         
X[regime_true==FALSE,]%*%B_true_1  

# Prior hyperparameter

b <- quantile(abs(X[,K]),0.9) # upper bound for r
b_min <- quantile(abs(X[,K]),0.1) # lower bound for r
V <- 1e-10*diag(N)
v <- 1e10

B <- matrix(0, nc=N, nr=K)
Lambda <- 1e-10*diag(K)

# Sampling scheme for Multivariate linear regression
gibbs_mls <- function(Y, X, V, B, v, Lambda){

    B_post <- solve(crossprod(X, X) + Lambda)%*%( crossprod(X, Y) +     Lambda%*%B)

    U_post <- Y - X%*%B_post
    v_post <- v + nrow(Y)    
    V_post <- V + crossprod(U_post, U_post) + t(B_post - B)%*%Lambda%*%    (B_post-B) 

    Sigma <- MCMCpack::riwish(v_post, V_post)

    Lambda_post <- crossprod(X,X) + Lambda
    inv_Lambda_post <- solve(Lambda_post)

    Z <- matrix(rnorm(ncol(Y) * ncol(X)), ncol(X), ncol(Y))
    B_draw <- B_post + t(chol(inv_Lambda_post)) %*% Z %*% chol(Sigma)

    U_draw <- Y - X%*%B_draw
    return(list(B = B_draw,
                Sigma = Sigma,
                U = U_draw))
}


# Sampler Gibbs MCMC

draws <- 2000
burn <- 1*draws
thining <- 4
sample <- vector("list",  1 + thining*draws + burn)
c <- 0.01

# Initial sample (conditional on r_init)
sample[[1]]$r <- median(abs(X[,K]),0.5) # initial value for r

############### sampler starts here
for(i in 1:(length(sample)-1)){
    # Create regime indicator and relevant data
    r_old <- sample[[i]]$r

    regime <- abs(X[,K])<r_old
    Y_0 <- Y[regime==TRUE,]
    Y_1 <- Y[regime==FALSE,]
    X_0 <- X[regime==TRUE,]    
    X_1 <- X[regime==FALSE,]    

    # Sample Sigma i and B i|Sigma i
    sample_sigma_beta_0 <- gibbs_mls(Y_0, X_0, V, B, v, Lambda)
    sample[[i+1]]$beta_0 <- sample_sigma_beta_0$B
    sample[[i+1]]$Sigma_0 <- sample_sigma_beta_0$Sigma

    U_0 <- sample_sigma_beta_0$U

    sample_sigma_beta_1 <- gibbs_mls(Y_1, X_1, V, B, v, Lambda)
    sample[[i+1]]$beta_1 <- sample_sigma_beta_1$B
    sample[[i+1]]$Sigma_1 <- sample_sigma_beta_1$Sigma

    U_1 <- sample_sigma_beta_1$U

    # MCMC in Gibbs 

    # Proposal of new value
    r_proposal <- exp(rnorm(1, log(r_old), sd=c))
    while(r_proposal> b | r_proposal < b_min) r_proposal <- exp(rnorm(1,     log(r_old), sd=c))

    # New regimes
    regime_proposal <- abs(X[,ncol(X)])<r_proposal
    Y_0_proposal <- Y[regime_proposal==TRUE,]
    Y_1_proposal <- Y[regime_proposal==FALSE,]
    X_0_proposal <- X[regime_proposal==TRUE,]    
    X_1_proposal <- X[regime_proposal==FALSE,]    

    T_0 <- nrow(Y_0)
    tilde_T_0 <- nrow(Y_0_proposal)

    T_1 <- nrow(Y_1)
    tilde_T_1 <- nrow(Y_1_proposal)

    tilde_U_0 <- Y_0_proposal - X_0_proposal%*% sample[[i+1]]$beta_0
    tilde_U_1 <- Y_1_proposal - X_1_proposal%*% sample[[i+1]]$beta_1

    log_acceptance_ratio <- log(det(sample[[i+1]]$Sigma_1))*(T_1 - tilde_T_1) + 
        log(det(sample[[i+1]]$Sigma_0))*(T_0 - tilde_T_0) + 
        1/2*sum(diag(solve(sample[[i+1]]$Sigma_1)%*%(crossprod(U_1, U_1) -     crossprod(tilde_U_1, tilde_U_1)))) +
        1/2*sum(diag(solve(sample[[i+1]]$Sigma_0)%*%(crossprod(U_0, U_0) - crossprod(tilde_U_0, tilde_U_0)))) +
    log(r_proposal/r_old)

    acceptance_ratio <- min(1, exp(log_acceptance_ratio))
    if(!is.finite(acceptance_ratio)) acceptance_ratio <- 1

acceptance <- runif(1) < acceptance_ratio
if(acceptance){
    r_new <- r_proposal
}else{
    r_new <- r_old
}

sample[[i+1]]$r <- r_new

sample[[i+1]]$acceptance <- acceptance

cat("Draw", i,": ",acceptance," new r: ",r_new,"\n")    
}

cat("Acceptance ratio: ", mean(sapply(sample, with, c(acceptance))))

sample <- sample[seq.int(from= burn + 1, to=length(sample), by =thining)]

plot(sapply(sample, with, c(r)))

Reduce('+', lapply(sample, `[[`, 1))/length(sample) - B_true_0
Reduce('+', lapply(sample, `[[`, 3))/length(sample) - B_true_1
Reduce('+', lapply(sample, with, r))/length(sample) - r_true
```

Comment: Your question is very long and it is hard to tell at a glance whether the issue is fundamental or due to a bug in your implementation. Since debugging is off-topic here, I suggest removing non-essential parts.